# Flutter Android app goes to background state by itself after a "logout"

Tags: android, flutter

I have a Flutter app which on logout replaces the view hierarchy with the login screen, and then shortly after goes to background by itself, the console emitting these messages:

```
I/BLASTBufferQueue(14271): [SurfaceView[com.example.MainActivity]#7] destructor()
I/BufferQueueConsumer(14271): [SurfaceView[com.example.MainActivity]#7(BLAST Consumer)7](id:37bf00000009,api:0,p:-1,c:14271) disconnect
I/BLASTBufferQueue(14271): [ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#6] destructor()
E/BLASTBufferQueue(14271): [ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#6](f:0,a:1) Applying pending transactions on dtor 1
I/BufferQueueConsumer(14271): [ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#6(BLAST Consumer)6](id:37bf00000008,api:0,p:-1,c:14271) disconnect
I/GED     (14271): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/BLASTBufferQueue(14271): releaseBufferCallbackThunk bufferId:61293478281243 framenumber:234 blastBufferQueue is dead
I/BLASTBufferQueue(14271): releaseBufferCallbackThunk bufferId:61293478281242 framenumber:1 blastBufferQueue is dead
I/FA      (14271): Application backgrounded at: timestamp_millis: 1691666857167
```

I am struggling to find out why and to prevent this from happening.

The logout does some cleanup but essentially just does:

```
                _navigator!.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                  LoginScreen.route(),
                  (route) => false,
                );
```

Comment: From the docs, note that:  To remove all the routes below the pushed route, use a RoutePredicate that always returns false (e.g. (Route<dynamic> route) => false).

Comment: Correct, that's my mistake. Can you post the widget that triggers the log out as well as your navigator setup?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in it, but I can't easily post the widget there's too much other stuff in there, it uses Bloc and the main app widget then does the call above - the navigator is a global key currentState.

Comment: But given that console output - it looks like Android system buffers are being disposed of and cause some kind of crash which backgrounds the app, but without apparent other damage - if I return to it and log back in it all works normally. So I am wondering if there is a package I am using that isn't cleaning itself up correctly?